# R optimization with fixed sum of parameters

Tags: r, optimization, parameters, sum, fixed

i want to optimize one function, with the sum of parameters set to 1
here there is the function

```
varxyz<-function(param){
a<-param[1]
b<-param[2]
c<-param[3]
a^2*matcov[1,1]+b^2*matcov[2,2]+c^2*matcov[3,3]+2*a*b*matcov[1,2]+2*a*c*matcov[1,3]+2*b*c*matcov[2,3]   
}  


parammv <- optim(c(0.3,0.3,0.4),varxyz,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.1,0.1,0.1))
```

where matcov is the covariance matrix

How can I set the sum of the three parameters to 1?
Thanks for answers

Comment: `?optim` to start with, maybe.

Comment: optimize with only 2 parameters, the third one being fixed as `c = 1 - (a + b)`

Comment: You're looking for `constrOptim`, take a look at `ui` and `ci` arguments. For further details see `?constrOptim`.

Comment: @Jilber `ConstrOptim` ? but how to set constraint =1? maybe by giviging 2 constraints >= 1 and <=1 , but I dont'think you can get a feasible solution. baptiste suggestion seems to be the solution here.

Comment: @baptiste I was thinking the same, but how would you specify a lower limit for c?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a quadratic optimization problem, you can use `quadprog`.

```
# Sample data
n <- 3
matcov <- var(matrix(rnorm(2*n^2),2*n,n))

library(quadprog)
solve.QP(matcov, rep(0,n), matrix(1,nc=1,nr=n), 1, meq=1)

# With lower- and upper-bound constraints:
solve.QP(
  matcov, rep(0,n), 
  cbind( 
    rep(1,n),  # Equality constraint
    diag(n),   # Lower bound constraint
    -diag(n)   # Upper bound constraint
  ),
  c(
    1,         # Equality constraint RHS
    rep(.1,n), # Lower bound
    rep(-1,n)  # - Upper bound
  ),
  meq = 1      # The first constraint is an equality
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
proj <- function(x) x / sum(x)

varxyz <- function(param) {
   param <- proj(param)
   ... rest of function as it is now ...
}
```

After performing the optimization apply `proj` to the solution from `optim` to get the answer.

You might also want to look into the `spg` function in the BB package as it supports projections natively.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sugestion of @baptiste and imposing a minimal value to `c` (0.1) via `ifelse`:

```
matcov <- var(matrix(rnorm(12),4,3))
varxyz<-function(param){
 a<-param[1]
 b<-param[2]
 c<-1-(a+b)
 ifelse(c >= 0.1,a^2*matcov[1,1]+b^2*matcov[2,2]+c^2*matcov[3,3]+2*a*b*matcov[1,2]+2*a*c*matcov[1,3]+2*b*c*matcov[2,3],-Inf)
}  


parammv <- optim(c(0.3,0.3),varxyz,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(0.1,0.1))
```

Comment: `Error in optim(c(0.3, 0.3), varxyz, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0.1,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
`